# Interaction of \BeforeBeginEnvironment and \NewEnviron

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, etoolbox

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{proof}{\tcblower}

\NewEnviron{solution}{\begin{proof}[Solution]%
\BODY%
\end{proof}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper box.
\begin{proof}[Solution]
My solution.
\end{proof}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper box.
\begin{solution}
My solution.
\end{solution}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The first `tcolorbox` displays as intended, whereas the second, which, naively, should produce the exact same thing, throws several errors:  extra `{`s, `\begin{xyz}` ended by `\end{notxyz}`, blah blah, etc. etc..

On the other hand, if I just use `\newenvironment{solution}{\proof[Solution]}{\endproof}`, the thing compiles fine, but the `\tcblower` is no longer appended before `\begin{solution}`, so this doesn't automatically get set into the lower box.

I have at least two questions regarding this:

First of all, is it possible to get `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` (and related commands) to work with `\<environment>` and `\end<environment>`?  Not only would this fix the problem, but, if this worked as one would hope, this provides a cleaner solution anyways (just one less package I have to load).

Secondly, what the hell is going on?  I mean just look at it:  this code is just *begging* to compile correctly!

Comment: The trouble is `tcolorbox` already uses `environ`. (And so you wouldn't save a package regardless.)

Comment: You can work around this. You can also add `\tcblower` to `\proof`. However, I think the more basic problem is the specific way in which the different `environ`s work and how `\tcblower` is implemented. Because you can use a `\NewEnviron` to wrap an existing `environ` environment. But I don't think that `\tcblower` is compatible with this.

Comment: There are times when I think wipet is right about LaTeX and many of those times involve `environ`. This is not a criticism of `environ`, really. (I can't do this because `prooftrees` not only uses `environ` but nests `environ` environments in the way I just said is possible.)

Comment: @cfr `\pretocmd{\proof}{\tcblower}{}{}` and `\apptocmd{\proof}{\tcblower}{}{}` both don't work.  Am I doing this wrong, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: one can do this with `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{solution}{\tcblower}` rather than `proof`

Comment: @touhami Sure, but then I would have to write this for every `\begin{proof}`/`\end{proof}` derivative.  It's not a big deal as in practice I'll only need one or two derivatives, which means I'll just have to write a couple extra lines.  I suppose simply the fact that this doesn't "just work" bothered me and I wanted to know why.

Comment: ok, I understand now.

Answer (score 8):

`\tcblower` is a very special marker which ends an environment (the content box of the upper part) and begins another environment (the content box of the lower part). Therefore, all environments and TeX groups of the upper part have to be closed, before `\tcblower` is used. This also means that you cannot already begin an environment or TeX group for the lower part and use `\tcblower` afterwards.

`\BeforeBeginEnvironment{proof}{\tcblower}` does the right thing, namely adding `\tcblower` **before** the `proof` environment begins.

On the other hand, `solution` creates a new environment where `\tcblower` implicitely is used **after** the begin of the environment.

The avoid the problem, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{myproof}[1][]{\begin{proof}[#1]}{\end{proof}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{myproof}{\tcblower}

\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{proof}[Solution]}{\end{proof}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{solution}{\tcblower}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper box.
\begin{proof}[Solution]
My solution.
\end{proof}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper box.
\begin{solution}
My solution.
\end{solution}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Here, `myproof` and `solution` are two final environments which get an additional `\tcblower`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could invoke a `\tcblower` for *both* the `proof` and `solution` environments and redefine `\tcblower` at the start of the `solution` environment so that you don't get a second `\tcblower` (which would cause the same problem that you encountered):

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{proof}{\tcblower}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{solution}{\tcblower}

\NewEnviron{solution}{%
    \def\tcblower{}% <--- was already added before \begin{solution}.
    \begin{proof}[Solution]%
        \BODY%
    \end{proof}%
}
```

Now *both* `tcolorbox` environments yield identical results:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{proof}{\tcblower}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{solution}{\tcblower}

\NewEnviron{solution}{%
    \def\tcblower{}%
    \begin{proof}[Solution]%
        \BODY%
    \end{proof}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper box.
\begin{proof}[Solution]
My solution.
\end{proof}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
Upper box.
\begin{solution}
My solution.
\end{solution}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```